Splitting a domain between a private and public BIND DNS server
I have a domain ( foo.com in this example) that currently has a public DNS server (namecheap) that has entries for www.foo.com and its associated MX records.
what I would like to do is have a private dns that would handle my internal servers for the internal users ( wiki.foo.com, postgres.foo.com, etc) and forward any other requests to the public dns. External users on the internet would not interact with the private dns, and continue as normal.
As is, my internal dns will resolve the private subdomains (wiki, etc) but does not resolve the public ones ( www) It seems that bind doesn't like to split a zone amongst two servers, unless I am missing something
I have my named.conf and zone files below, along with a drawing of what I would llike to accomplish if I haven't described my goals clearly.
Is there any way to do what I want, or am I looking at this from the wrong angle?

named.conf
options {

        listen-on port 53 {
                127.0.0.1;
                10.0.2.81;
        };

        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";

        allow-query { localhost; 10.0.1.0/24; 10.0.2.0/24; };
        allow-query-cache { localhost; 10.0.1.0/24; 10.0.2.0/24; };  

        recursion yes;

        dnssec-validation auto;

        forwarders {
            1.1.1.1; // Cloudflare    
            1.0.0.1; // Cloudflare  
            8.8.8.8; // Google     
            8.8.4.4; // Google 
        };
        forward first;

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

        /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
        include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";

};


logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
 channel query_log {
        file "data/named_query.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity info;
        print-time yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-category yes;
    };
    category queries { query_log; };

};


zone "foo.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/foo.com.zone";


};
zone "." IN {
       type hint;
       file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

Zone file
$TTL 86400
@    IN    SOA   ns1.foo.com. admin.foo.com. (
            2023122001 ; Serial (YYYYMMDDNN)
            3600       ; Refresh
            1800       ; Retry
            1209600    ; Expire
            86400 )    ; Minimum TTL

     IN    NS    ns1.foo.com.

; Define the internal DNS server's A record
ns1      IN    A     10.0.2.81


; Internal A records for internal DNS resolution
system    IN    A     10.0.1.32
xmpp      IN    A     10.0.1.24


why not use .local for local domain?

@alexus don't use .local, it is reserved for Multicast DNS and shouldn't be mixed with normal DNS.

The internal name server thinks it is authoritative for example.com, causing it not to perform any recursion for the domain. It is recommended to use a subdomain (e.g. internal.example.com or int.example.com) for the internal resources. If the internal name server is only authoritative for the subdomain it won't interfere with other records in the parent zone.
If you don't use a subdomain you would have to add all the external records to the internal zone and keep them up-to-date.

I was afraid of that, I was hoping there was something simple that I had missed

You could use a workaround with Response Policy Zone (rpz) for your local domain. It works by a form of DNS hijacking, but I do not how well it works with any DNSSEC validation settings? Maybe you have to use validate-except on local DNS server to disable DNSSEC validation for your own domain. It won't interfere with how the rest of the world query your official DNS server.
